# Non-singular elliptic curve parametrization

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, parametrization, elliptic-equations

It is known that some singular elliptic curves can be expressed with parametric equations.

For example :
$y^2=x^3$ can be parametrized with $x=t^2$ and $y=t^3$
$y^2=x^3+x^2$ can be parametrized with $x=t^2-1$ and $y=t^3-t$ [[source](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1108.6219.pdf)]

But, is there any parametric equations for some non-singular elliptic curves with a graph looking like :
[simple elliptic curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IVyc.png)
And if yes, what would be the correct way to obtain it.

We could assume that it can be represented by : $y^2 = f(x)$
where $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+c$ have only one simple real root.

Comment: There are no rational parametrization.  You need the elliptic functions or similar.

Comment: Thank you ! However I didn't said it but i'm not necessarily looking for a rational parametrization

Comment: @Yoshi "rational" means the parameters live in $\mathbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$.

Comment: Sorry but, what's the question?

Comment: @KennyWong Oh ok, translation mistake ! Thank you !

Comment: @JoséAlejandroAburtoAraneda It could be : "Is there a parametrization for $y^2=x^3-3x+4$ ?"

Comment: @Yoshi Anyway, assuming you want the parameters to live in $\mathbb C \cup \{ \infty \}$, then you're not going to be able to find this kind of parameterisation for smooth elliptic curves. This is a consequence of the Riemann-Hurwitz theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, there are not "singular elliptic curves", you want to say "singular curves given by a Weierstrass equation".

Now, if you want to do such parametrization (through polynomials) to a curve given by a Weierstrass equation, if the curve is non-singular, that can not be done. If your curve $C$ is defined over $\mathbb{P}^2$ over $\mathbb{C}$, you will have a regular (holomorphic) map 
\begin{align}
\phi:\mathbb{P}^1\to C.
\end{align}
By the Riemann-Hurwitz Theorem, as $\phi$ is surjective, the genus of the codomain must be less or equal to the genus of the domain. But, the genus of $C$ is $1$, and the genus of $\mathbb{P}^1$ is zero.